# Designing layouts with <div> in JSF

Tags: html, jsf-2, primefaces

I am designing my web in JSF2.0. To keep the web simple and clean, I used  tag and inside  I used JSF. Each  tag has some style="width:--px; height=--px;" associated. Now when JSF content goes more then some extent, the JSF panel gets outside from the layout. There is some layout issue. Should I remove declaration of style attribute from each  tag?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an absolute layout (using explicit pixel sizes in every element) and you have dynamic data, you are bound to run into problems sooner or later.

You should think about reworking your layout to something more flexible. A good start might be to have a look at CSS frameworks like [Blueprint](http://blueprintcss.org/) or [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/) to reduce the amount of work you have to put into it.

Comment: ya... here by defining pixels inside <div> i am bounding my layout in a specific dimension. i am following the frameworks suggested by you. thank you so much. i will contact you later, if i encounter any problem. thank you.